# Is it possible to minimize wrapper pattern to one-liner?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, wrapper

Consider such scenario, you have some data, but you don't want to expose it directly, besides there is some logic involved. So you write something like this:

```
private string field;
public string Field
{
  get { return this.field; }
  set 
  {
     // some logic with previous value
     this.field = value;
     // some logic with new value
  }
}
```

Ok, cool, but once you write this for N-th time you have enough, so you write a class -- wrapper for it. Since you don't want to expose the implementation you write this:

```
private Wrapper<string> field = new Wrapper<string>();
public string Field
{
  get { return this.field.value;}
  set { this.field.value = value; }
}
```

So, ok, common code is hidden, implementation not exposed, but still there is a lot of repetitions.

The question -- is it possible to squeeze it further?

*Above it is my main question about the pattern in C#, but I leave this for comment -- is there a language which supports this pattern to a degree that only single line is required. Something like this:*

```
public string Field { get; set; } <- new Wrapper<string>(); // pseudo code
```

Comment: Use code snippet - very handy in your case, and cheaper then another language

Comment: @Fabio, AFAIK snippets are OK when **creating** code (writing) but once they are in code you have to handle them manually. So it is not solution per se, it is just a way of automate typing, not for managing the code in total.

Comment: You can use snippet for "typing" your Wrapper class. In this case your managed logic stay in one place -> in your wrapper class

Comment: If you write same logic more then one time - then you create a method or as you did a new type which contains that logic. _but still there is a lot of repetitions_ - it is ok, you using your nice Wrapper right. For example does nullable `MyNullableProperty.Value` is repetetion too?

Answer (score 2):

In C#, I believe you could create an implicit conversion between `Wrapper<string>` and `string` such that you can declare:

```
public Wrapper<string> Field { get; set; }
```

And then assign a string to the property:

```
MyObject.Field = "test string";
```

You can read more about implicit conversions here: [implicit (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx), or look at [this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010066/implicitly-casting-a-generict-back-to-t).

Comment: This is good! Thank you, but if I am not mistaken on incoming conversion the wrapper would be created again which means the need of wiring it again (like some connection to database, or something similar).

Comment: Conversions only for set and read all value will become a performance issue in the future

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with C# 6.0

```
public string Field { get; } = new Field<string>();
```

Comment: That's getter only. Doesn't handle setting.

Comment: Only readonly properties which doesn't change underlying value.

Comment: @Phani -- can you explain how this answer is a "new question"?